# Apriori algorithm in R, not negative rules

Tags: r, algorithm, associations, apriori

I have a large binary data set where I wish to run an apriori algorithm in R. The problem is at the algorithm is making rules of all the 0's, where I only wish to look at the 1's. 
As for example get these rules:

```
        lhs                                                        rhs     support   confidence lift      count
[1]    {SPA=0,SPD=0,SPE=0,SPF=1,SPJ=0}                         => {SPC=0} 0.2036065 0.9866727  1.0174854  6515
[2]    {SPA=0,SPD=0,SPE=0,SPF=1}                               => {SPC=0} 0.2163885 0.9864653  1.0172715  6924
[3]    {SPA=0,SPD=0,SPF=1,SPJ=0}                               => {SPC=0} 0.2070754 0.9852788  1.0160479  6626
```

Does anyone know how to only look for the rules where the variables are 1 and not 0? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control this using the `appearance` argument to `apriori`. Since you do not provide data,  I will use the built-in Adult data as an example, but I think that you need to add `appearance=list(rhs = "SPC=1")` to your apriori statement.

### Example

I will generate only rules for which the rhs is native-country=United-States

```
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
    parameter = list(supp = 0.4, conf = 0.6, 
        minlen=2, target = "rules"),
    appearance=list(rhs = "native-country=United-States")
)

inspect(rhs(rules[1:5]))
    items                         
[1] {native-country=United-States}
[2] {native-country=United-States}
[3] {native-country=United-States}
[4] {native-country=United-States}
[5] {native-country=United-States}
```

### Addition

I thought that you only wanted SPC=1 on the rhs. Based on your comments, I now think that you want to generate rules that contain no XYZ=0 items at all.  You can also get this with `appearance`. First identify the possible items with XYZ=0, then use appearance to exclude these.  I do not know what your variables are called, so I am calling the transactions `TransactionData`

```
## identify items to exclude
excluded <- grep("=0", itemLabels(TransactionData), value = TRUE)
```

Then add this to your `apriori` statement.

```
appearance=list(none = excluded)
```

Comment: I am not seeing the data,  but also please add your code to the question - your `apriori` statement

Comment: Thank you! A small example of the data looks like this

ID SPA SPB SPC SPD SPE SPF SPG SPHSPI SPJ
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
5 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
6 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0

I have tried solving for for example SPF=1. Then I get 
[1]   {SPB=1,SPH=0,SPJ=1} => {SPF=1} 0.01335852 0.6827586  1.5240735   99 
[2]   {SPB=1,SPC=0,SPJ=1} => {SPF=1} 0.01794630 0.6683417  1.4918917  133
So still a lot of 0's on the left hand side. 
Is there any way to not look for 0's at all?

Comment: So you mean that you do not want any XYZ=0 at all? Adding to answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to make the matrix logical before you create the transactions. For matrix `m` you can do the following:

```
storage.mode(m) <- "logical"
trans <- as(m, transactions)
```